# How to non-verify mobile number user redirect to verification page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

If user is logged in then if his mobile number is verified then he will allow to move index.php else he will move to mobileverify.php. So i write a function and call this function in index page if  unverified user tries to move in index.php function will redirect him mobileverify.php but function is not working please see the code below and tell me where i am wrong

```
function mobile_verify(){
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
$login = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='$login'");
$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
$verify = $row['verify'];
if($verify === ""){
header('Location: mobileverify.php');
exit();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_num_rows($query);
```

returns the number of rows in the result set not the values.

try

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: if i add `mysql_fetch_array($query)` it say  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS but i have one mobile_verify();

Answer (score 0):

you are basically fetching the *no of rows* meeting your `WHERE` clause.

**IT DOES NOT RETURN THE DATA ITSELF**

you could use
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);` 
and then check

```
$verify = $row['verify'];
if(!$verify){
header('Location: mobileverify.php');
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
}
```